# Online db2 REORG TABLE with the NOTRUNCATE TABLE option requests Z-lock on a table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Db2 11.5.7, Windows.
The situation is the same on other versions and platforms like 11.1.4.6 & AIX.

Steps to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE (I INT NOT NULL, C CHAR (100) DEFAULT '') IN USERSPACE1;

-- Insert 10K rows
INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE (I) 
WITH T (I) AS (VALUES 1 UNION ALL SELECT I+1 FROM T WHERE I<10000)
SELECT I FROM T;

-- Delete almost all of them
DELETE FROM DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE WHERE I BETWEEN 10 AND 10000-2;
CALL ADMIN_CMD ('RUNSTATS ON TABLE TEST_REORG_ONLINE WITH DISTRIBUTION AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL');

-- Just for test
CALL SYSPROC.REORGCHK_TB_STATS ('T', 'DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE');

-- Lock a row from another session:
db2 +c "SELECT * FROM DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE WHERE I=10000 WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS"

-- Just for test
SELECT L.*
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_LOCKS ('<table_schema>DB2ADMIN</table_schema><table_name>TEST_REORG_ONLINE</table_name><lock_object_type>Table</lock_object_type>', -2)) L;

-- Fire the online REORG with NOTRUNCATE TABLE
CALL ADMIN_CMD ('REORG TABLE DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE INPLACE NOTRUNCATE TABLE');

-- Z-lock from the "Online" reorg
SELECT 
  U.APPLICATION_HANDLE, U.APPLICATION_NAME, U.UTILITY_DETAIL
, U.OBJECT_SCHEMA, U.OBJECT_NAME
, L.LOCK_CURRENT_MODE, L.LOCK_MODE_REQUESTED, L.LOCK_STATUS
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_UTILITY (-2)) U
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_APPL_LOCKWAIT (U.APPLICATION_HANDLE, U.MEMBER)) L ON 1=1
WHERE (U.OBJECT_SCHEMA, U.OBJECT_NAME, U.UTILITY_TYPE) = ('DB2ADMIN', 'TEST_REORG_ONLINE', 'REORG')
```

| APPLICATION_HANDLE | APPLICATION_NAME | UTILITY_DETAIL | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | LOCK_CURRENT_MODE | LOCK_MODE_REQUESTED | LOCK_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7373 | db2reorg | REORG TABLE "DB2ADMIN"."TEST_REORG_ONLINE" INPLACE NOTRUNCATE TABLE | DB2ADMIN | TEST_REORG_ONLINE | IS | Z | C |

Moreover, if I open another session, lock another row with, say, with the following statement, end the 1-st locking transaction (with commit or rollback), then REORG will still wait on lock with the same Z-lock request.
`db2 +c "SELECT * FROM DB2ADMIN.TEST_REORG_ONLINE WHERE I=10000-1 WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS"`

It's interesting, that if I lock some of the "first" rows (like with WHERE I=1), Z-lock is not placed.
So, it seems that the "NOTRUNCATE TABLE" option simply doesn't take an effect sometimes.

Does somebody see the same behavior?

Comment: I also get an IS lock with Z LOCK_MODE_REQUESTED. Tried on 11.5.8 Linux